# Either 'orElse' operation on functions returning Eithers and EitherTs

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz

It's fairly easy to chain `Either` or `\/` types in Scala/Scalaz in order to recover from left side 'fail' values.

How can get the same behavior but for functions `(T1, T2) => Future[A \/ B]`?

I've been able to break this down in two separate directions, but unable to combine the solutions.

It's easy to chain `Future[A \/ B]` by simply leveraging Scalaz's `EitherT` as `type FutureEither[A, B] = EitherT[Future, A, B]` and a monad instance for `Future`.

I've been able to also chain `(T1, T2) => A \/ B` types by using `EitherT`:

```
  implicit def wrapTransform[T1, T2, A, B](f: Function2[T1, T2, A \/ B]) = EitherT[({ type λ[α] = Function2[T1, T2, α] })#λ, A, B](f)
  implicit def unwrapTransform[T1, T2, A, B](e: EitherT[({ type λ[α] = Function2[T1, T2, α] })#λ, A, B]): Function2[T1, T2, A \/ B] = e.run

  // some dummy functions
  def times2(fail: Boolean, v: Int): String \/ Int = if (fail) "times2:FAILED".left else (v * 2).right
  def fail(v1: Boolean, v: Int): String \/ Int = "fail:FAILED".left
  def alwaysPlus1(ignore: Boolean, v: Int): String \/ Int =  (v + 1).right

  val times2_times2 = (times2 _) orElse (times2 _)
  val alwaysPlus1_times2 = (alwaysPlus1 _) orElse (times2 _)

  Console println times2_times2(false, 10) // prints '\/-(20)'
  Console println times2_times2(true, 10) // prints '-\/(times2:FAILED)'
  Console println alwaysPlus1_times2(false, 10) // prints '\/-(11)''
  Console println alwaysPlus1_times2(true, 10) // prints '\/-(11)'
```

How do you write a transformer that works for two levels of nesting for types `(T1, T2) => Future[A \/ B]`?

My knowledge of functional programming is still in the works, so I apologize for poor wording and term usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you had e.g. an `Option` instead of a `Future`, you could add a layer to the stack:

```
def wrap[T1, T2, A, B](f: (T1, T2) => Option[A \/ B]) = EitherT[
  ({ type L1[a] = OptionT[
    ({ type L2[b] = (T1, T2) => b })#L2, a
  ] })#L1, A, B
](OptionT[({ type L2[b] = (T1, T2) => b })#L2, A \/ B](f))
```

It's a mess, but you can fill in the types fairly mechanically, since you just move from the inside out—e.g. our `(T1, T2) => Option[A \/ _]` becomes an `EitherT[OptionT[(T1, T2) => _, _], A, _]`

The problem is that if you want to do this with `Future`, you'll need a `FutureT`, and the consensus is that since it's [not possible to write `FutureT` without blocking](https://github.com/robinp/akkaz/issues/3), [it's better not to provide it](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/issues/10).